# Complexity of polynomial inequalities

Tags: computational-complexity, real-algebraic-geometry

What is known about the complexity of deciding whether a finite set of polynomial inequalities in $n$ real variables with integer coefficients is satisfiable? Decidability is guaranteed by Tarski's theorem
(see the answers to [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/36638/56920)), but his proof is nonconstructive and gives no complexity bound.

Comment: This computational problem is known as the [existential theory of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals). It sits somewhere between NP and PSPACE, but not much more is known; it’s important enough that it’s been given a complexity class of its own ($\exists\mathbb R$). (The official definition as in the Wikipedia article allows the arbitrary existential sentences, but this easily reduces to the case of satisfiability of a single polynomial equation by introduction of a few extension variables.)